# Assistance solving the IVP $y'''-5y''+100y'-500y=0$; $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=10$, $y''(0)=250$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $y'''-5y''+100y'-500y=0$; $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=10$, $y''(0)=250$

So the characteristic equation is:

$r^3-5r^2+100r-500=0$

And when factored gives:

$(r-5)(r^2+100)$

I wasn't really sure what to do here because this doesn't seem like it fits any of the equations that I use to form a general solution, but this is what I can up with:

$y(t)=c_1e^{5x}$

$y'(t)=5c_1e^{5x}$

$y''(t)=25c_1e^{5x}$

So solving this:

$y(0)=0=c_1e^{5(0)}=c_1$

But going any further is pointless since $c_1$ is $0$.  So this makes me think I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Well you have roots $r_{1, 2, 3} = 5, \pm~ 10i$. This means cosine and sine terms from the complex imaginary roots (Euler's), so you have $y_c(x) = c_1 e^{5 x} + c_2 \cos (10 x) + c_3 \sin (10 x)$. Please proceed.

Comment: @Moo that makes sense now.  I was lazy and used wolfram to factor, had I used the quadratic formula I would have seen this.  As always, Moo, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I learned in my ODE class, you are on the right track.

This is a third-order linear homogenous equation, which means your answer should have *three* terms, according to the principle of superposition. You have one term, given from the real root of your characteristic equation. Your missing two terms are in the imaginary roots, which require the use of Euler's formula. Try solving for that and applying the initial conditions.